# Can I use typographically quotation marks in HTML's meta tag

Tags: html, noindex

I've found a site where one meta tag is looking like that:

```
<meta name="”robots”" content="”noindex,nofollow”">
```

Please not that the values for both attributes is additionally enclosed in typographical quotation marks: `"” ... ”"`.

While wondering if that is legal, I've checked with a SEO-checking page which is saying that the page is using indeed the `noindex` tag.

My question: who is right? Are the typographical quotation marks ignored? I could not really find a good answer while googling.

Comment: That’s definitely a mistake, but there are lots of mistakes in real-world HTML so I wouldn’t be surprised if some crawlers were able to recognize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typographic quotes are part of the attribute value.

The [documentation from Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag) describes the values `robots` (for the `name` attribute) and `noindex` and `follow` (for the `content` attribute) and says that "Multiple directives may be combined in a comma-separated list".

It does not describe the values `”robots”`, `”noindex` or `nofollow”`

Some clients may ignore `”` characters. I would not assume that all or even many will. I wouldn't trust a syntax checker that didn't pick up on them as an error.